# How to Copy Link from android app?

Tags: applications, stock-android, android-versions

[image: Link Inside pages]

Hello sir/mam how can i copy a link from any android app that has link inside pages

I have some whatsapp group joining link inside app 
Every pages has a link of Whatsapp group i want to copy that link can u help me....
Your help is highly appreciated...

App link is

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsappgroupinvite

Answer (score 0):

**How To Create WhatsApp Group Invitation Link**

Only Group Admin can create Invitation link to let join other people using this. Other participants of the Group cannot see this link until this link is shared by the Group Admin. You can create WhatsApp Group LinkTo create WhatsApp Group Invite Link, just follow the simple steps given below:

Step 1:
 Open your WhatsApp Group –> Tap the subject of the Group,    here just scroll down and you will get the list of participants with two more options: ‘Add Participants‘ and ‘Invite via link‘.

Step 2:
 Tap on ‘Invite via link‘ and on the next screen, you will    get ‘Join Link’ for your WhatsApp Group. Now you have to share this link with anyone to join it.

For sharing the link, you will get a direct option to share from this screen ‘send link via WhatsApp’ or you may also use ‘Copy Link’ & ‘Share Link’ options as well.

In case if you want to cancel/revoke this link, just tap on ‘Revoke Link’ option. The old invite link will not be working anymore. You can again create a new invitation link for the same WhatsApp Group.
That’s It.

This feature is widely used where you want to add a number of people in your Group. Instead of manually adding one by one manually, just a share will work for you.

*REFERENCES*

[create-whatsapp-group-invitation-link-join - mashnol.org](https://www.mashnol.org/create-whatsapp-group-invitation-link-join/)

Comment: I think this doesn't really answer the question. OP is asking how they can "copy" links that are included in apps

Comment: "Every pages has a link of Whatsapp group i want to copy that link can u help me..."    i think that the question is not verry straight forward, however the fact that the question included "I want to copy that Link" means that they aren't interested in other apps..

Comment: They need a way to copy those links, I assume those links are included in every row (see the screenshot). Or may be I may have misunderstood?

Comment: I'm not sure what the desired anwer is, but as far as i can tell, the only links in the screenshot are links to groups on WhatsApp  so the answer would be Step 1:
 Open your WhatsApp Group –> Tap the subject of the Group, here just scroll down and you will get the list of participants with two more options: ‘Add Participants‘ and ‘Invite via link‘.   ... however if the questioners desired answer includes hard coded links, it's not possible.. this is because it's probably not hard coded at all, it downloads a list from the WhatsApp server ( user based ) and shows the list in a ListView..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to decompile the app APK file. Assuming the links are hard-coded, you could be able to get them in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

search google play for open with and pick an app from the list and install it

I assume you will have notepad app or office app on your android

from open with app choose the notepad app to open links

now go to your app and click the links you want

copy links from the notepad app